# Query friendships table (with pairs of rows) to find mutual statuses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema

```
Relationship:

fromId (fkey)
toId (fkey)
isFriend (boolean)
isBlocked (boolean)
```

A user requests friendship by adding a record with fromId set to his id and toId set to the friend's id and isFriend=true.

To accept the request, the other user does the same but ids reversed.

They are only friends when both records exist and both have isFriend=true.

I'm trying to make a query that lists a users' friends given an ID (WHERE userId = x)

This is what I started with:

```
SELECT "a"."fromId" AS "userId1", "a"."toId" AS "userId2", "b"."fromId" AS "userId2", "b"."toId" AS "userId1"
FROM "Relationship" a
INNER JOIN "Relationship" b
ON "a"."fromId" = "b"."toId" AND "b"."fromId" = "a"."toId"
WHERE "a"."isFriend" = true AND "b"."isFriend" = true
```

This is the result I get with

[image: Query results]

With this, I'm able to get only the relationships that have records in both directions (friends), but what I'm trying to get (if possible), are only the IDs of the friends of a user

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from "Relationship" a
where
    a."fromId" = x and a."isFriend" and
    exists (
        select 1
        from "Relationship" b
        where
            b."toId" = x /* b."toId" = a."fromId" */ and
            b."isFriend");
```